# My array is undefined

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, leaflet

I have the following problem code is further down.
When I'm doing this

```
city[i] = response[i].name;
```

I can print out every name of every city I have. But now I want to have a multi dimensional array because I want to save also the following code

```
L.marker([response[i].lat, response[i].lon]).bindPopup(response[i].name);
```

And I thought that I can save it in a multidimensional array, so when we have as an example

```
city[1]["CityName"] = "New York"
city[1]["Locations"] =  L.marker([location]).bindPopup(name);
```

So, now when I call `city[1]['Locations']` I get the L.Marker, right?

This here is my code

```
function init()
{
region = 'all';
var url = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    attribution = "(c) OSM contributors, ODBL";

var minimal = L.tileLayer(url, {styleID: 22677, attribution: attribution});
$.ajax
({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'webservice.php',
    data: {region: region},
    success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) 
    { 
        var city = new Array();
        var lygStr = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
        {
            //alert(response[i].lat + " | " + response[i].lon + " | " + response[i].name);
            alert(response[i].name);
            city[i]["CityName"] = response[i].name;

            //L.marker([response[i].lat, response[i].lon]).bindPopup(response[i].name);
            if(i + 1 == response.length)
            {
                lygStr += city[i]["CityName"];
            }
            else
            {
                lygStr += city[i]["CityName"] + ", ";
            }
        }
        alert("Test" + lygStr);
        var cities = L.layerGroup([lygStr]);

        map = L.map("map1", 
        {
            center: new L.Latlng(resposne[1].lat, response[0].lon),
            zoom: 10,
            layers: [minimal, cities]
        });
    }
});

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper initialization will fix this problem - You need to initialize the Object at position `city[i]` to be an object which holds your values rather than undefined.

```
    var city = [];   // don't use new Array() !
    var lygStr = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
    {
        city[i] = {}; // you need to create an object here

        city[i]["CityName"] = response[i].name;
```

also, you want to have an object rather than an array. Arrays can only have numeric indices while object can have identifiers like you want.

```
    city[i]['Location']
    // same as
    city[i].Location
```

Comment: What do you mean by city[i] = []? When I let it all the same, but init the array as you said I still get an error in this line `city[i]["CityName"] = response[i].name;`

Comment: @devShuba that was a typo, you need a object `{}` and not an array `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in this line:

```
city[1]["Locations"] =  L.marker([location]).bindPopup(name);
```

that your `city[1]["Locations"]` will be set to whatever `.bindPopup(name)` returns.  This could be `undefined` or it could be a function.  Is that method constructed to return a object its called on?  What about just this:

```
city[1]["Locations"] =  L.marker([location]);
city[1]["Locations"].bindPopup(name);
```

Comment: it's a simple initialization problem;)

Answer (score -1):

You're using `city[i]` as an array before ever declaring it as such:

```
var city = []; // don't use the new Array(); syntax
var lygStr = '';

for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    // before using city[i] as an array, you must declare it as an array
    city[i] = [];    

    city[i]["CityName"] = response[i].name;
    ...
```

Comment: actually one should use an object instead of an array here.

Comment: Yes, but apparently it is wrong. Arrays have numeric indices. This code accidently works because you can attach properties to the Array-Object. Try the following code: `city=[];city["foo"]="bar";alert(city.length) // 0, meeep`.